# How can I add un-mappable information (Room number, etc) to a Google Maps address?

Tags: google-maps

I am using the new Google Maps.

Let's say I have a meeting at the following building:

- Computer Seminar, Room 1234, [70A Berkeley, CA 94720](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=70A+Berkeley%2C+CA+94720&data=!4m15!2m14!1m13!1s0x80857c3b7d08721f%3A0x49396d1e65694b6!3m8!1m3!1d4269!2d-122.2517509!3d37.8758174!3m2!1i1728!2i1041!4f13.1!4m2!3d37.875822!4d-122.25173)

Or this one:

- PuppetConf, Puppet Fundamentals, Fountain Room, [The Fairmont San Francisco Hotel](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=The+Fairmont+San+Francisco+Hotel&data=!1m4!1m3!1d5386!2d-122.4009011!3d37.7927113!2m3!3m1!3b1!6s0x8085808ce36415bd%3A0xf3b8a6769ec21ea5!4m30!2m16!1m14!1s0x0%3A0xcf0541d7a109ef4!3m8!1m3!1d5386!2d-122.4009011!3d37.7927113!3m2!1i1280!2i656!4f13.1!4m2!3d37.7923885!4d-122.4105048!5e4!6sFairmont+Hotel!5m12!1m11!1sFairmont+Hotel!4m8!1m3!1d12609!2d-122.2699664!3d37.8085301!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!17b1)

These buildings have 100 rooms and it is easy for attendees to get lost on their way to the meeting.

Can I somehow include information such as the room number in the Google Maps page in a way that allows Google Maps to still show the location, and not using coordinates? If I include information like room numbers, nearby landmarks, etc. then Google Maps is unable to find the location. For example, Google Maps is unable to handle any information like this:

- [Computer Seminar, Room 1234, 70A Berkeley, CA 94720](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Computer+Seminar%2C+Room+1234%2C+70A+Berkeley%2C+CA+94720&data=!4m10!1m9!4m8!1m3!1d136625!2d-122.316337!3d37.863474!3m2!1i1728!2i1041!4f13.1)
- [(PuppetConf, Puppet Fundamentals, Fountain Room) The Fairmont San Francisco Hotel](https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=%28PuppetConf,+Puppet+Fundamentals,+Fountain+Room%29+The+Fairmont+San+Francisco+Hotel&data=!4m10!1m9!4m8!1m3!1d136625!2d-122.316337!3d37.863474!3m2!1i1728!2i1041!4f13.1)

  However, Google Maps does not know the room numbers inside this building. How can I add

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can add a room number in the Google Maps page. Google Maps uses the US address format so that room numbers appear after the street address. For example: 25 Main St, #101, Washington, DC  20019-4649 USA.